# Install TBB on Linux 11.04

Tags: linux, installation, tbb

I have been searching google and tbbs forums on how to install TBB.

I have downloaded both the linux and source from: 
http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=175

Extracted them using tar -xvf, and then ran the make file.
Then I went to `tbb/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.5.2_libc,13_kernel2.6.38_debug/` and ran `tbbvars.sh`

I also tried running `tbb/build/generate_tbbvars.sh`, then `tbbvars.sh` and `tbbvars.csh`

No matter what I ty when I try to compile a program with `-ltbb`, i get
`/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libtbb.so when searching for -ltbb
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltbb`

Any one know how to fix this?

`Linux damian-HP-Z600-Workstation 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: What's the output of `file /usr/lib/libtbb.so`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another instance of the issue answered lucidly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052542/gcc-m32-flag-usr-bin-ld-skipping-incompatible). You have libraries of one bit width and are trying to link them into a compilation of a different bit width. If both your application compile process and your TBB build process were done on the same system, one of them must have done the wrong thing when deciding whether to output 32-bit code or 64-bit code.

Comment: Thanks you, I was reusing an old make file, and I just copied and pasted the parameters...