# Linker won't find -lglut

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

SO.

I'm a little new to the Linux dev world (without an ide), so please be patient.

**The Issue**

I have a make file constructed which compiles about 7-8 files into `.o` files which are then linked together with a few libraries. I have done locates on these libraries, and their dev counterparts *do* exist. The problem is that the linker refuses to find them. My output (if I am reading this correctly) tells me that it's looking in the wrong area. I've exported my `LD_PATH` to include `/usr/lib`, which is where my `.so.` files are. My main question is, how do I get `-lglew` and `-lglut` to link up with each other? I would also like to put my `.o` files in my `obj` folder and my binaries in a `bin` folder. Is this possible in a makefile? If so, given my make file, what would be the best recipe to do this?

**The Makefile**

```
  1 BIN = bin/
  2 OBJ = obj/
  3 TARGET = opengl_03
  4 DEPS = main.o  displayinit.o initializer.o algorithms.o matrix3f.o window.o vertex3.o
  5 CC = g++
  6 CFLAGS = -g -m32
  7 LIBS = -lglut -lGLEW
  8 INCLUDEPATH = -L/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib
  9 
 10 $(TARGET) : $(DEPS)
 11     $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET)  $(DEPS) $(BIN)
 12 
 13 displayinit.o : displayinit.cpp displayinit.h
 14     $(CC) -c displayinit.cpp $(OBJ)
 15 initializer.o : initializer.cpp initializer.h
 16     $(CC) -c initializer.cpp $(OBJ)
 17 algorithms.o : algorithms.cpp algorithms.h
 18     $(CC) -c algorithms.cpp $(OBJ)
 19 matrix3f.o : matrix3f.cpp matrix3f.h
 20     $(CC) -c matrix3f.cpp $(OBJ)
 21 vertex3.o : vertex3.cpp vertex3.h
 22     $(CC) -c vertex3.cpp $(OBJ)
 23 window.o : window.cpp window.h
 24     $(CC) -c window.cpp $(OBJ)
 25 main.o : main.cpp
 26     $(CC) -c main.cpp $(OBJ)
 27 
 28 clean:
 29     rm $(DEPS) 
 30 
 31
```

**Output**

```
g++ -lglut -lGLEW  -L/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib -g -m32  -o opengl_03  main.o  displayinit.o initializer.o algorithms.o matrix3f.o window.o vertex3.o bin/
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libglut.so when searching for -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libglut.a when searching for -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../libglut.so when searching for -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../libglut.a when searching for -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libglut.so when searching for -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libglut.a when searching for -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLEW
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find bin/: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [opengl_03] Error 1
```

I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: You're compiling using `-m32` to build a 32-bit version, but it looks like your `/usr/lib/libglut.so` (and other glut libraries) is a 64-bit library? Run the command `file /usr/lib/libglut.so` to see.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052542/gcc-m32-flag-usr-bin-ld-skipping-incompatible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Linux are you using? It looks like you're using a 64-bit system, but trying to compile a 32-bit application (because of -m32 compiler switch). So either remove the -m32 or install the 32-bit development libraries. They may be named like freeglut-32bit or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libglut.so when searching for -lglut

It means ld found libglut.so, but it is not good candidate for -m32 target.

PS, BIN is a dir, why do you put it into compile object?

```
$(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET)  $(DEPS) $(BIN)
```

Comment: I thought that was what was needed to move it into a my bin folder. Is there another way?