# How can i make -lalleg on the linker to work?

Tags: c++, allegro4

Well, i did all i knew to work with allegro in C++ but i keep getting the same problem,
-lalleg not found

D:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible D:\Program *Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib/liballeg.a when searching for -lalleg
D:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible D:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../liballeg.a when searching for -lalleg
D:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    cannot find -lalleg
E:\Programacion\C++\Practicas\Allegro\Testing\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status*

i tried to make DevC++ to send the -lalleg at compiling but i keep getting that
,if i don't put the compiler to use -lalleg

i get this

*D:\Users\J****n\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz9vWbS.o  In function `_mangled_main()':
4       E:\Programacion\C++\Practicas\Allegro\Testing\Main.cpp  undefined reference to `_install_allegro_version_check'
D:\Users\J****n\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz9vWbS.o   In function `WinMain':
7       E:\Programacion\C++\Practicas\Allegro\Testing\Main.cpp  undefined reference to `_WinMain'
E:\Programacion\C++\Practicas\Allegro\Testing\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status*

any of you know of any possible solution
i'm using Allegro 4.2.2 and the last version of DevC++

the code is something basig ,just a test

```
int main(){
    allegro_init();
    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

any help is welcome,thank you for the time

Comment: Where did you get the compiled library version get from? Can you compile it on your machine from scratch?

Comment: ***skipping incompatible*** Are you mixing 32 and 64 bit here? Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052542/gcc-m32-flag-usr-bin-ld-skipping-incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052542/gcc-m32-flag-usr-bin-ld-skipping-incompatible)

Comment: >Where did you get the compiled library version get from? Can you compile it on your machine from scratch? – πάντα ῥεῖ\

I get it from the github https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/releases/tag/v4-2-2

and i don't know how to do that,i'm still learning,i completed my C++ course like 7 months ago and now i want to learn how to use allegro 4.2